# Regarding Pitru rituals

Tags: vedas, puranas, sri-vaishnava, yajur-veda

Recently one of my close relatives passed away.

So, there are some rituals being done in the name of "Maasiyam and Oonam"

I am not sure what are those rituals and why it is being done?

Also, there is one procedure called "Sodhakumbam"

Can someone tell me what are those procedures and why are they done?

Please also help me to understand what are the other rituals that need to be done for Pitrus with an year of passing?